# How to use different executors in one @Async

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

This is about how to use different executors, when calling the same method  with @Async annotation.

The problem is that we want to have a retry (and logging) policy for some external calls. All this logic is in a method with @Async annotation and the business logic to be executed is passed to it (a Runnable):

```
@Async(value = "DefaultTaskExecutor}")
public void executeAsyncAndRetry(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    ...
}
```

But we want that depending on the call, a different thread pool would be used.

I think this @Async annotation doesn't allow el for taking the executor from the parameters or something like that.

Is there any other way of configuring that annotation for this, or a different approach to just having different methods with different executors specified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to define a executor bean in spring context file and pass that bean id inside @Async("executor id") like this.

```
<bean id="otherExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>


@Async("otherExecutor")
void doSomething(String s) {
    // this will be executed asynchronously by "otherExecutor"
}
```

For more info please refer: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html